# SSRS Report Variable issue Visual Studio 19

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, visual-studio-2019

I am writing an SSRS report in Visual Studio 19. When I have no variables in the query, I get all of the records that I am looking for. When I add in a variable, then enter it in the box when I preview the report, I get no values returned. The variable is @ASN in the code below.

```
SELECT
    `RCV_ASN0`.`BUSINESS_UNIT_ID` AS `Business Unit`, 
    `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` AS `Facility ID`, 
    `RCV_ASN0`.`ASN_ID` AS `ASN ID`, 
    `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`DESCRIPTION` AS `ASN Status`, 
    `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`ITEM_ID` AS `Item ID`,
    CASE 
        WHEN `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`DESCRIPTION` = 'Verified'
            THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN NOT ( `FAC_FACILITY_RCV_ASN10`.`TIME_ZONE` IS NULL ) THEN CONVERT_TZ(`RCV_ASN0`.`UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`, 'SYSTEM', `FAC_FACILITY_RCV_ASN10`.`TIME_ZONE`)
                    ELSE `RCV_ASN0`.`UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`
                END
        ELSE NULL
    END AS `ASN Verified Date`, 
    SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY`) AS `Quantity`,
    `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME` AS `Unit Volume`,    
    cast(SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY` * `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`) as decimal(18,3)) AS 'Total Unit Volume',
    CASE
        WHEN `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` = 5001 THEN cast(SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY` * `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`) as decimal(18,3))/77
        WHEN `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` = 6241 THEN cast(SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY` * `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`) as decimal(18,3))/67
        WHEN `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` = 8251 THEN cast(SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY` * `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`) as decimal(18,3))/77
        WHEN `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` = 4501 THEN cast(SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY` * `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`) as decimal(18,3))/64
        ELSE 9999
    END AS 'Pallet Equivalent',
    CASE
        WHEN `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` = 5001 THEN ceil(cast(SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY` * `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`) as decimal(18,3))/77)
        WHEN `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` = 6241 THEN ceil(cast(SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY` * `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`) as decimal(18,3))/67)
        WHEN `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` = 8251 THEN ceil(cast(SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY` * `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`) as decimal(18,3))/77)
        WHEN `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` = 4501 THEN ceil(cast(SUM(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`QUANTITY` * `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`) as decimal(18,3))/64)
        ELSE 9999
    END AS 'PE Rounded'
        
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        `RCV_ASN`.`ORG_ID` AS `ORG_ID`, 
        `RCV_ASN`.`UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` AS `UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`, 
        `RCV_ASN`.`FACILITY_ID` AS `FACILITY_ID`, 
        `RCV_ASN`.`ASN_STATUS` AS `ASN_STATUS`, 
        `RCV_ASN`.`ASN_ID` AS `ASN_ID`, 
        `RCV_ASN`.`BUSINESS_UNIT_ID` AS `BUSINESS_UNIT_ID`
    FROM
        `default_receiving`.`RCV_ASN` `RCV_ASN` 
    WHERE 
        `RCV_ASN`.`ORG_ID` IN ( 
            '4501', 
            '5001', 
            '6241', 
            '8251', 
            '9' ) AND
        `RCV_ASN`.`FACILITY_ID` IN ( 
            '4501', 
            '5001', 
            '6241', 
            '8251' ) AND
        concat(`RCV_ASN`.`ORG_ID`, `RCV_ASN`.`FACILITY_ID`) IN ( 
            '45014501', 
            '62416241', 
            '50015001', 
            '82518251' )
    ) `RCV_ASN0`
        INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT distinct
            `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS`.`ORGANIZATION_ID` AS `ORGANIZATION_ID`, 
            `RCV_ASN_STATUS`.`ASN_STATUS_ID` AS `ASN_STATUS_ID`, 
            `RCV_ASN_STATUS`.`DESCRIPTION` AS `DESCRIPTION`
        FROM
            `default_receiving`.`RCV_ASN_STATUS` `RCV_ASN_STATUS`, 
            `default_configsync`.`CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS` `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS` 
        WHERE 
            `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS`.`ORGANIZATION_ID` IN ( 
                '4501', 
                '5001', 
                '6241', 
                '8251', 
                '9' ) AND
            `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS`.`PROFILE_PURPOSE` = 'system' AND
            `RCV_ASN_STATUS`.`PROFILE_ID` = `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS`.`PROFILE_ID`
        ) `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`
        ON 
            `RCV_ASN0`.`ASN_STATUS` = `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`ASN_STATUS_ID` AND
            `RCV_ASN0`.`ORG_ID` = `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`ORGANIZATION_ID`
            INNER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT
                `RCV_LPN`.`ASN_ID` AS `ASN_ID`, 
                `RCV_LPN`.`FACILITY_ID` AS `FACILITY_ID`, 
                `RCV_LPN`.`ORG_ID` AS `ORG_ID`, 
                `RCV_LPN`.`PK` AS `PK`,
                
                concat(`RCV_LPN`.`ORG_ID`, `RCV_LPN`.`FACILITY_ID`)
            FROM
                `default_receiving`.`RCV_LPN` `RCV_LPN` 
            WHERE 
                `RCV_LPN`.`ORG_ID` IN ( 
                    '4501', 
                    '5001', 
                    '6241', 
                    '8251', 
                    '9' ) AND
                `RCV_LPN`.`FACILITY_ID` IN ( 
                    '4501', 
                    '5001', 
                    '6241', 
                    '8251' ) AND
                concat(`RCV_LPN`.`ORG_ID`, `RCV_LPN`.`FACILITY_ID`) IN ( 
                    '45014501', 
                    '62416241', 
                    '50015001', 
                    '82518251' )
            ) `RCV_LPN6`
            ON 
                `RCV_LPN6`.`ASN_ID` = `RCV_ASN0`.`ASN_ID` AND
                `RCV_LPN6`.`ORG_ID` = `RCV_ASN0`.`ORG_ID` AND
                `RCV_LPN6`.`FACILITY_ID` = `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID`
                INNER JOIN 
                (
                SELECT
                    `RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`ORG_ID` AS `ORG_ID`, 
                    `RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`LPN_DETAIL_ID` AS `LPN_DETAIL_ID`, 
                    `RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`ITEM_ID` AS `ITEM_ID`, 
                    `RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`LPN_PK` AS `LPN_PK`, 
                    `RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`FACILITY_ID` AS `FACILITY_ID`, 
                    `RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`BUSINESS_UNIT_ID` AS `BUSINESS_UNIT_ID`
                FROM
                    `default_receiving`.`RCV_LPN_DETAIL` `RCV_LPN_DETAIL` 
                WHERE 
                    `RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`ORG_ID` IN ( 
                        '4501', 
                        '5001', 
                        '6241', 
                        '8251', 
                        '9' ) AND
                    `RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`FACILITY_ID` IN ( 
                        '4501', 
                        '5001', 
                        '6241', 
                        '8251' ) AND
                    concat(`RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`ORG_ID`, `RCV_LPN_DETAIL`.`FACILITY_ID`) IN ( 
                        '45014501', 
                        '62416241', 
                        '50015001', 
                        '82518251' )
                ) `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`
                ON 
                    `RCV_LPN6`.`PK` = `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`LPN_PK` AND
                    `RCV_LPN6`.`ORG_ID` = `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`ORG_ID` AND
                    `RCV_LPN6`.`FACILITY_ID` = `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`FACILITY_ID`
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    (
                    SELECT distinct
                        `FAC_FACILITY`.`FACILITY_ID` AS `FACILITY_ID`, 
                        `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS`.`ORGANIZATION_ID` AS `ORGANIZATION_ID`, 
                        `FAC_FACILITY`.`TIME_ZONE` AS `TIME_ZONE`
                    FROM
                        `default_facility`.`FAC_FACILITY` `FAC_FACILITY`, 
                        `default_configsync`.`CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS` `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS` 
                    WHERE 
                        `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS`.`ORGANIZATION_ID` IN ( 
                            '4501', 
                            '5001', 
                            '6241', 
                            '8251', 
                            '9' ) AND
                        `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS`.`PROFILE_PURPOSE` = 'fac::facilityConfig' AND
                        `FAC_FACILITY`.`PROFILE_ID` = `CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS`.`PROFILE_ID`
                    ) `FAC_FACILITY_RCV_ASN10`
                    ON 
                        `RCV_ASN0`.`ORG_ID` = `FAC_FACILITY_RCV_ASN10`.`ORGANIZATION_ID` AND
                        `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID` = `FAC_FACILITY_RCV_ASN10`.`FACILITY_ID`
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                        (
                        SELECT distinct
                           pid.`BUSINESS_UNIT_ID` AS `BUSINESS_UNIT_ID`, 
                            itf.`ITEM_ID` AS `ITEM_ID`, 
                            pid.`ORGANIZATION_ID` AS `ORGANIZATION_ID`,
                            itf.VOLUME
                       FROM `default_item_master`.`ITE_ITEM_FACILITY` itf
                            left join `default_configsync`.`CFG_PROFILE_INFO_DETAILS` pid
                            on pid.`PROFILE_PURPOSE` = 'ite::itemMasterFacilityConfig'
                                AND itf.`PROFILE_ID` = pid.`PROFILE_ID`
                        WHERE 
                            pid.`ORGANIZATION_ID` IN ( 
                                '4501', 
                                '5001', 
                                '6241', 
                                '8251', 
                                '9' ) 
                        ) `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`
                        ON 
                            `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`ITEM_ID` = `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`ITEM_ID` AND
                            `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`ORG_ID` = `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`ORGANIZATION_ID` AND
                            (`RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`BUSINESS_UNIT_ID` IS NULL AND
                            `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`BUSINESS_UNIT_ID` = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' OR
                            `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`BUSINESS_UNIT_ID` = `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`BUSINESS_UNIT_ID`)
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                            (
                            SELECT
                                `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL`.`FACILITY_ID` AS `FACILITY_ID`, 
                                `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL`.`LPN_DETAIL_ID` AS `LPN_DETAIL_ID`, 
                                `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL`.`ORG_ID` AS `ORG_ID`, 
                                `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL`.`QUANTITY` AS `QUANTITY`
                            FROM
                                `default_receiving`.`RCV_RECEIPT` `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL` 
                            WHERE 
                                `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL`.`ORG_ID` IN ( 
                                    '4501', 
                                    '5001', 
                                    '6241', 
                                    '8251', 
                                    '9' ) AND
                                `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL`.`FACILITY_ID` IN ( 
                                    '4501', 
                                    '5001', 
                                    '6241', 
                                    '8251' ) AND
                                concat(`RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL`.`ORG_ID`, `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL`.`FACILITY_ID`) IN ( 
                                    '45014501', 
                                    '62416241', 
                                    '50015001', 
                                    '82518251' )
                            ) `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`
                            ON 
                                `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`ORG_ID` = `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`ORG_ID` AND
                                `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`LPN_DETAIL_ID` = `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`LPN_DETAIL_ID` AND
                                `RCV_LPN_DETAIL8`.`FACILITY_ID` = `RCV_RECEIPT_LPN_DETAIL18`.`FACILITY_ID` 
WHERE 
    `RCV_ASN0`.`ASN_ID` = @ASN and 
    -- 'B232367' AND
    `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`DESCRIPTION` IN ( 
        'In Receiving', 
        'Verified', 
        'Open' ) AND
    (date(
        CASE 
            WHEN `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`DESCRIPTION` = 'Verified'
                THEN
                    CASE 
                        WHEN NOT ( `FAC_FACILITY_RCV_ASN10`.`TIME_ZONE` IS NULL ) THEN CONVERT_TZ(`RCV_ASN0`.`UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`, 'SYSTEM', `FAC_FACILITY_RCV_ASN10`.`TIME_ZONE`)
                        ELSE `RCV_ASN0`.`UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`
                    END
            ELSE NULL
        END) = (CURRENT_DATE + interval floor(-1) day) AND
    `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`DESCRIPTION` = 'Verified' OR
    `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`DESCRIPTION` = 'In Receiving') 
GROUP BY 
    `RCV_ASN0`.`BUSINESS_UNIT_ID`, 
    `RCV_ASN0`.`FACILITY_ID`, 
    `RCV_ASN0`.`ASN_ID`, 
    `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`VOLUME`,
    CASE 
        WHEN `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`DESCRIPTION` = 'Verified'
            THEN
                CASE 
                    WHEN NOT ( `FAC_FACILITY_RCV_ASN10`.`TIME_ZONE` IS NULL ) THEN CONVERT_TZ(`RCV_ASN0`.`UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`, 'SYSTEM', `FAC_FACILITY_RCV_ASN10`.`TIME_ZONE`)
                    ELSE `RCV_ASN0`.`UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`
                END
        ELSE NULL
    END, 
    `RCV_ASN_STATUS2`.`DESCRIPTION`, 
    `ITE_ITEM_RCV_LPN_DETAIL14`.`ITEM_ID` 
ORDER BY 
    `ASN ID` ASC,
    `Item ID` ASC
```

I tried removing all of the single quotes from the query, changing the data type of the parameter, inputting multiple values for the parameter (That exist in the database), using single and double quotes around the input values and inputting the value for the variable as a specified available value. None of that returned the records for the specified parameter.

Comment: start by tagging the question with the RDMS you are using and also cleaning up the question so it's legible, I doubt anyone will want to read all that as it stands.